# Can't resolve 'thrift'

Tags: node.js, angular, thrift

I installed  thrift in my win 10 machine and y try to run an angular service that uses thrift generated files.

I added to the package JSON
   "@types/thrift": "^0.10.9",
    "thrift": "^0.13.0",
but when I run keep getting the next error where Session is a thrift generated file

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'thrift' in '/mnt/c/Users/....../src/app/shared/thrift- 
connector'
ERROR in ./src/thrifts/Session.js
```

Than starts with :
    "use strict";

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var Thrift = thrift.Thrift;
```

I generate the files with  a npm scripy:

```
"thirft": "thrift -r --out src/thrifts -I thrifts --gen js:node thrifts/all.thrift"
```

I also tested this in a ubuntu WSL but with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this instaling the repositroy version of thrift

```
  "thrift": "git+https://github.com/apache/thrift.git",
```

Answer (score 0):

the latest version 0.14.2 resolves this but if you need 0.13 specifically you can reinstall with 0.13.0-hotfix.1

```
npm install thrift@0.13.0-hotfix.1
```

beware, this version of thrift doesn't include q although if you install it through npm it will also install it as a separate module